# to extract specific columns from a csv file and copy it to another using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which is actually a matrix of 0's and 1's.  I need to exclude those columns that have 0's and pick only those that have 1's and copy them to another CSV file.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    reader=csv.DictReader(open("test1.csv","r"),[])

for data in reader:
        if data==1:
                print data
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to exclude all columns that have **any** zeroes in them, then first you need to read the whole file in memory -- because only after having seen every row will you know which columns have any zeroes!  This is a *logical* need -- whatever language you use the need will remain, it's intrinsic to the problem

So, for example:

```
allrows = list(reader)
```

Now, `allrows` is a list of dictionaries, whose items are strings, presumably `0` or `1`.  Now, you could do:

```
keepcols = [c for c in allrows[0] if all(r[c] != '0' for r in allrows)]
```

...not the fastest approach, but hopefully very, very simple to understand!

Once you do know which columns you want to keep, prepare a `DictWriter` instance `w` with those columns as the headers and the `extrasaction='ignore'` argument (so it will ignore "extra" keys in the dicts passed to it, and finally

```
w.writerows(allrows)
```

If you mean something different than "exclude all columns which have any zeroes in them", then please clarify exactly **what** you do mean by "i need exclude those columns that have 0's" because I can't interpret it differently.

Comment: you have interpreted it correctly... i mean to  "exclude all columns which have any zeroes in them".... but i did not understand the extrasaction and headers part... pl elaborate 

thank you so much... :)

Comment: Not much to elaborate -- just read http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader and use `fieldnames` for what I called `headers`.

Comment: @Anand, may *seem* wrong to you, but after assigning `allrows` a list of dicts I just copied and pasted it to my Python 2.6 interpreter and it doesn't _seem_ wrong to **it**... and I suspect a Python interpreter is more likely to be correct than you, when it comes to right or wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("test1.csv", "r"), [])

for data in reader:
    if data[column header] != 0:
         print data[column header]
```