# How to extract the specific columns from a csv file and write a new csv for it, in python

Tags: python, list, memory, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file and i want to extract some specific columns from it. How can I do that?
I have a dictionary of headings and the cell location like:

```
dict = {'Col1' : [(4,5)], 'Col2' : [(4,7)], 'Col3' : [(4,9)]}
```

I want to extract the data starting from the values of dict, till the end of the csv file!

For example:

```
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,Col0,Col1,,Col2,,Col3,Col4,
,,,bgr,abc,,efg,,hij,123,
,,,cde,klm,,nop,,qrs,123,
,,,asd,tuv,,wxy,,zzz,456,
,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,
```

I want to extract

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
abc,efg,hij
klm,nop,qrs
tuv,wxy,zzz
```

and write it in a new csv file! please help me doing this!
I want to efficiently handle this situation!

Comment: How do those indices work? `(5, 4) == 'klm'` and `(4, 5) == '')`, or is it `(3, 4) == 'col1'` ? And then, what's the rule for continuing to read columns... Maybe you could show us your current code that you feel isn't that efficient...

Comment: You can use `csv.dictwriter` and `csv.dictreader`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

Comment: This is similar to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209515/to-extract-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-and-copy-it-to-another-using-python?rq=1`

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is a library with a powerful [method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv) to read csv files.

In the case you want to read each column from the same row, the following script will do the work (note that only 2 python lines are useful):

```
import pandas as pd


# Give the name of the columns
colnames = ('skip1', 'skip2', 'skip3', 'Col0','Col1','skip4','Col2','skip5','Col3','Col4','skip6')
# Give the number of lines to skip
nbskip=4
# Give the number of rows to read (you can also filter rows after reading and remove the empty ones)
nrows=3
#List of columns to keep
keep_only = ('Col1','Col2','Col3')

#Read the csv
df =  pd.io.parsers.read_csv('test.csv', 
                 header=None,
                 skiprows=nbskip,
                 names=colnames,
                 nrows=nrows, # Remove if you prefer filter rows
                 usecols=keep_only)

# If the number of lines to keep is unknow,
# you can remove empty lines here

#Save the csv
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```